# How set schema name dynamically in @Table annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two schema "schema1" and "schema2" and also have two projects. Some of tables are in schema2 that are saving through schema1 project with annotation

```
@Table(name = "table", schema = "schema2")
```

where I mention schema name. But now my requirement is I want to specify schema dynamically in annotation So Suggest 
1. Is it possible to specify schema name in runtime
2. and If possible how can we achieve it?

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: we are support these all  mysql, oracle, postgres and Sql server.

Answer (score 1):

You can move schema to hibernate config properties file and use two different hibernate config file for two project

File 1

```
      hibernate.default_schema=schema1
```

File 2

```
      hibernate.default_schema=schema2
```

Comment: Is there a dynamic way to do this if I have one project and 2 schemas in the DB?